# I got some problems in adding the prime numbers to an array list

Tags: java

In this problem, I have a variable N.User will input the value of N.So, I have to find the prime number between 2 to N and store them in an array

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(10);
        int num,i,j,count;
        num = sc.nextInt();

        for(i=2;i<=num;i++){
            count = 0;
            for(j=2;j<= num/2;j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
                if(count==0){
                    array.add(i);
                }
            }

        for(int val: array){
            System.out.print(val + " ");
        }
        }
    }
```

So, if N=15.The output should be `2 3 5 7 11 13`
But I'm getting `11 13`
where is the problem?

Comment: I recommend writing a function to check if a number is prime. This will help you determine whether the problem exists in your outermost loop or within your prime number algorithm. E.g. `private static boolean isPrime(int n)`, and `if (isPrime(i)) { array.add(i); }`

Comment: "The output should be `2 3 5 7 11 13 15`"? 15 is not prime!

Comment: Replace num by " i " in the second for loop, [ for(j=2;j<= num/2;j++) ]

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: also you can try more greedy approach so it will be faster: instead of `for(j=2;j<= i/2;j++)` try something like `for(j=2;j * j < i && count == 0; j++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to optimize your search for primes you should use a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or at least add some simple limitations to your algorithm.  I have included a version with comments.  The main point of this is to only divide by primes that you have already found.

1. After 2, only check odd numbers since even numbers are guaranteed to be composite (i.e. non-prime).
2. Only divide by primes already computed.
3. Only divide by primes <= to the square root of the candidate. If n is divisible by m to yield q.  Then n is also divisible by q to yield m.  No need to repeat the test with higher numbers.  The threshold is the square root of the candidate.

```java
      List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
      primes.add(2); // seed list with first prime

      int max = 50;
      // only check odd numbers after 2.
      for (int candidate = 3; candidate < max; candidate += 2) {

         // loop thru existing primes
         for (int p : primes) {
            // if candidate is divisible by any prime, then discontinue
            // testing and move on to next candidate via outer loop
            if (candidate % p == 0) {
               break;
            }
            // if the limit has been reached, then a prime has been
            // found, so add to list of primes and continue with
            // next candidate.
            if (p * p > candidate) {
               // add new found prime to list
               primes.add(candidate);
               break;
            }
         }
      }

      System.out.println(primes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is mixed up, think about what defines a prime number. A prime number is a number that is only divisible by itself and one. So when you check that the remainder equals zero and then increase the count a prime number then wouldn't be added to the array as the `count != 0`. I do realise you set the limit to j for num / 2 but not sure what your thought process there was. I've added an alternative solution (I've tried to stick to yours and just alter it slightly).

My thought process is that by the time a prime number is divided by itself it should only have produced a remainder of zero that one time.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
int limit = 100;
int i, j;

for (i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
        count = 0;
        j = 2;
        for (j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
            if(i%j == 0){
                count += 1;
            }
            if (j == i && count == 1) {
                array.add(i);
            }
        }

    }
```